# Can't compile while Google Drive is running

Tags: qt, compilation

I compile all my stuff using Qt and run Google Drive all the time. So if I compile my project once, debug a little and then recompile quickly, Google Drive is uploading my files so I can't compile - this can last up to a minute due to Australian upload speeds. So I quit Google Drive, forget to open it up again and then the next day my files aren't synced when I am university.

I never had this problem when using DropBox (I assume it copies the files before uploading).

Any way around this menacing problem?

Comment: Obviously don't compile in a directory mirrored by Google Drive. Use real version control like Git, and push the repo to a remote (bare repo) backed by drive.

Comment: github is one of the free solutions